# What is Bismuth's view on the "shattering" of Pink Diamond?

Tags: steven-universe

If Bismuth knows that Rose's sword can only poof gems, and not shatter them (since she was the one who made the sword to begin with), did she know the "shattering" was fake; or did she not bother to think about it? Bismuth must not have been at the location, because she would have had suspicions that something was off.

Should this be moved to a discussion or is this an okay question?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything intrinsic about Rose's sword that makes it *unable* to shatter gems. As we can see with Amethyst's cracked gem in the first season, a gem can be cracked or shattered with enough force directly applied, not just with special weapons such as the Breaking Point, which is specially designed to shatter gems directly rather than attacking and poofing their forms.

Thus, I see no reason to believe Bismuth suspected that Pink Diamond's shattering was fake.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I just thought she had said that she had made the sword to specifically poof gems and not shatter them, correct me if I'm wrong.